# Did anyone have a "ReferenceError: React is not defined" in Roles & Permissions after creating Strapi API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, strapi

I didn't have any problem until today. I wanted to create a new Strapi API but I always get a

```
ReferenceError: React is not defined
```

in a Roles & Permissions settings menu when I would like to modify a role.
Roles are listed:

[Roles & Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL9eV.png)

But when I try to modify one of them I get it:

[Trying to modify them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBllW.png)

I tried creating an app with yarn and npx. The result was the same for both of them. I tried also creating it with sqlite and postgres.

I can just add that my old one API is still working properly.

Strapi version: 3.0.3

Comment: Did you find what is the problem? I have exactly the same problem :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy the solution from [Strapi GitHub closed issue, reply by user: soupette](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/6733).

Hello @everyone there is an open PR that fixes the issue we are really sorry about this issue and it should not have happened. In the meantime until the release is made here's a workaround to make your administration works:

**Create a the extensions/users-permissions/admin/src/components/Controller/index.js file:**

```
mkdir -p extensions/users-permissions/admin/src/components/Controller
touch extensions/users-permissions/admin/src/components/Controller/index.js
```

**Copy the following content:**

```
/**
 *
 * Controller
 *
 */
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { get, map } from 'lodash';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
import pluginId from '../../pluginId';
import { useEditPageContext } from '../../contexts/EditPage';
import InputCheckbox from '../InputCheckboxPlugin';

import { Header, Label, Separator, Wrapper } from './Components';

function Controller({ actions, inputNamePath, isOpen, name, inputSelected, setInputSelected }) {
  const { selectAllActions } = useEditPageContext();

  const areAllActionsSelected = () => {
    return Object.keys(actions).every(action => actions[action].enabled === true);
  };

  const handleChange = () => {
    selectAllActions(`${inputNamePath}.controllers.${name}`, !areAllActionsSelected());
  };

  const hasSomeActionsSelected = () => {
    return Object.keys(actions).some(action => actions[action].enabled === true);
  };

  const setNewInputSelected = name => {
    setInputSelected(name);
  };

  const labelId = areAllActionsSelected() ? 'unselectAll' : 'selectAll';

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Header>
        <div>{name}</div>
        <Separator />
        <div className="checkbox-wrapper">
          <div className="form-check">
            <Label
              className={`form-check-label ${areAllActionsSelected() &&
                'checked'} ${!areAllActionsSelected() &&
                hasSomeActionsSelected() &&
                'some-checked'}`}
              htmlFor={name}
            >
              <input
                className="form-check-input"
                checked={areAllActionsSelected()}
                id={name}
                name={name}
                onChange={handleChange}
                type="checkbox"
              />
              <FormattedMessage id={`${pluginId}.Controller.${labelId}`} />
            </Label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Header>
      <div className="row">
        {map(Object.keys(actions).sort(), actionKey => (
          <InputCheckbox
            inputSelected={inputSelected}
            isOpen={isOpen}
            key={actionKey}
            label={actionKey}
            name={`${inputNamePath}.controllers.${name}.${actionKey}.enabled`}
            setNewInputSelected={setNewInputSelected}
            value={get(actions[actionKey], 'enabled')}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

Controller.defaultProps = {
  actions: {},
  inputNamePath: 'permissions.application',
  name: '',
};

Controller.propTypes = {
  actions: PropTypes.object,
  inputNamePath: PropTypes.string,
  isOpen: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string,
};

export default Controller;
```

**Rebuild your app**

```
# Using yarn
yarn strapi build --clean
# Using npm
npm run strapi build --clean
```

Comment: btw, my Strapi version: 3.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue today.

There was a latest release v3.0.4 in which included the fix for this bug.

https://github.com/strapi/strapi/releases/tag/v3.0.4